# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined

Tags: angular

Estoy trayendo datos de un usuario a la interfaz y yo creo que estoy configurando mal mi interfaz y por eso es que me aparece el error del titulo.

Les muestro el código:

```
 import {IUser} from '../../app-interfaces'

 public DataUser: IUser
 ngOnInit(): void {
//TRAER LOS DATOS DEL USUARIO EN SESION
this.user.userData()
  .subscribe(
    res =>{
      this.DataUser = res
    },
    err =>{
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
```

Interfaz:

```
export interface IUser extends Document {
nombre: string;
apellido: string;
username: string;
email: string;
birth: string;
sexo: string;
seguidos: string;
seguidores: string;
password: string;
}
```

En el frontend no tengo ningún problema, muestro los datos como deben ser sin problema, pero cuando abro la consola me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: Captura de pantalla del error]

Éste es el HTML:

```
:129: <div class="data-user">
:130:    <span>{{ DataUser.nombre }} </span>
:131:    <span>{{ DataUser.apellido }} </span>
:132: </div>
```

Aclaro que los datos se muestran correctamente. El único problema es que me aparece ese error en la consola.

En un primer momento lo solucioné y era un problema de la interfaz `IUser`, pero luego refactorizé el código y me olvidé de cómo lo había solucionado y estoy seguro que es la interzaz de usuario o, al menos, estoy colocando mal el `public: DataUser: IUser`.

Comment: Si es un dato asíncrono deberías mostrarlo únicamente cuando lo hayas obtenido o bien darle un valor inicial mientras se hace la carga con, por ejemplo, `this.DataUser = {nombre: '-', apellido: '-'};`.

Answer (score 4):

El problema que sufres es debido a que el contenido de la variable `DataUser` no se definirá hasta que se resuelva la promesa, por lo que no podrás acceder a sus propiedades hasta entonces.

Una manera de resolver este problema es accediendo a la información únicamente cuando ésta llegue usando [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe):

```
<div class="data-user" *ngIf="DataUser | async as dataUser">
  <span>{{ dataUser.nombre }} </span>
  <span>{{ dataUser.apellido }} </span>
</div>
```

Nota que el nombre de la variable ha cambiado de `DataUser` a `dataUser`.

Otra forma de hacerlo es a través de un valor inicial:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  /* Valor inicial hasta que lleguen los datos */
  this.DataUser = {
    nombre: '-',
    apellidos: '-'
  };
  //TRAER LOS DATOS DEL USUARIO EN SESION
  this.user.userData()
  .subscribe(
     res =>{
       this.DataUser = res
     },
     err =>{
       console.log(err);
     }
  );
}
```

Una tercera forma de solucionar el problema, aunque no te recomiendo acostumbrarte a ella, es hacer uso del [operador de navegación segura (`?`)](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) para detectar la disponibilidad del dato:

```
<div class="data-user" *ngIf="DataUser | async as dataUser">
  <span>{{ (DataUser | async)?.nombre }} </span>
  <span>{{ (DataUser | async)?.apellido }} </span>
</div>
```

Comment: ambas respuestas me ayudaron, muchisimas gracias por su tiempo sabiendo la hora que es, mil gracias

Comment: Existe una tercera opción. Acabo de de editar mi respuesta para agregarla. Por cierto, aquí es temprano :)

Comment: aqui son las 3 de la madrugada xd, muchisimas gracias de verdad

Answer (score 2):

La obtencion de los datos es asincrono, por lo que tratas de pintar un dato sin si quiera obtenerlo, debes poner un renderizado condicional, o mostrar un spinner o algo mientras la data se carga en el componente, y una vez ese componente no sea null, ahi si renderizarlo

```
<div *ngIf="DataUser" class="data-user">
   <span>{{ DataUser.nombre }} </span>
   <span>{{ DataUser.apellido }} </span>
</div>
```